# htaccess,url aliases, mod_rewrite. Exclude id from url but needing it

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello the problem I'm having is this, I have a landing page (event.php) that shows events from my DB.

Each event among other fields has 'category','title','id'. I'm trying to create clean urls for my website that will look like this http://domain.com/event/category/title but the problem is that some events might have the same title because they might repeat weekly or so, altho they do have unique id, which I use to get the specific event.

My question is this, how could I transform something like:

```
http://www.domain.com/event.php?cat=rock&title=Great-gig&id=145
```

into:

```
http://www.domain.com/event/rock/Great-gig
```

Keep in mind that I do need the value of id but I dont want it to be shown on the clean url somehow...

I can create clean urls with htaccess but I can't figure out how to exclude the id from being seen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options only:

1. make an alias, for example, Great-gig-Dec if the event in december, Great-gig-Jan if it is in January and use this value as your unique id
2. load only the next event, or the most recent event, depending on your structure of site. This way if there are more than one Great-gig then you get the latest or the next, so you  can structure your url like http://www.domain.com/next-events/rock/Great-gig,  http://www.domain.com/latest-events/rock/Great-gig . So here you know which one of the many rows to use while it still looks like a good url.

maxim

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exclude it and use it anyway. You have to either pass it, or find the event using the title.

Comment: So there is no workaround to it ? since i have events with the same title i have to pass the id and it will be visible right ?

Comment: Yep. You should pass a slug corresponding to the title instead of the title. It will make sure your url is valid. And you can make it unique to use it as an identifier.

Comment: I'm sorry my english are not so good what do you mean by slag ? could you explain please :)

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to write htacces for that in your folder create a .htaccess file

in that write this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/  //for localhost
RewriteBase /              // for online

RewriteRule ^event/(.+)/(.+)/?$ event.php?cat=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```